# orthogonal binary sequences

Tags: binary, orthogonality

How to show that two binary sequences are orthogonal?
For an example verify whether **[0110001]** and **[0011101]** are orthogonal

Comment: The concept of orthogonality relies on the concept of inner product and two vectors are called orthogonal if their inner product equals zero.  What inner product are you using for these sequences?  $\langle u,v\rangle = \sum (u)_i(v)_i$?  Are you working with $\mathbb{F}_2$ as your scalar field or something else?

Comment: I came across this while learning linear block codes. In the lesson it says the code words derived from parity check matrix are orthogonal to code words derived from the generator matrix. I don't know how to answer above question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your specific inner product, I will assume that the inner product is given by $\langle u,v\rangle = \sum(u)_i(v)_i$ and that we are working in $\mathbb{F}_2^7$ as our vector space (i.e. the space of binary sequences of length seven).

So, the inner product between the two is given by multiplying each position together and then adding:

$\begin{array}{llllllll}&\color{red}{0}&\color{brown}{1}&\color{orange}{1}&\color{green}{0}&\color{blue}{0}&\color{purple}{0}&1\\
\times & \color{red}{0}&\color{brown}{0}&\color{orange}{1}&\color{green}{1}&\color{blue}{1}&\color{purple}{0}&1\\
\hline
&\color{red}{0}+&\color{brown}{0}+&\color{orange}{1}+&\color{green}{0}+&\color{blue}{0}+&\color{purple}{0}+&1
\end{array}$

In the context of $\mathbb{F}_2$, you have $1+1=0$.

Since $\langle u,v\rangle = 0$, these two sequences are indeed orthogonal.